# Add a suffix based on the values of a variable

Tags: sas

is there a way to add a suffix to Ids based on a column? Suppose to have:
For example:

> ```
>    ID       Suffix       
>   0001         1     
>   0001         1       
>   0001         1       
>   0001         1       
>   0001         2       
>   0001         2  
>   0002         1
>   0002         2   
>   0002         2   
>   0002         1    
>   .....     ....
> ```

Desired output

> ```
>    ID        
>   0001_1     
>   0001_1      
>   0001_1              
>   0001_1            
>   0001_2      
>   0001_2  
>   0002_1
>   0002_2   
>   0002_2   
>   0002_1    
>   .....
> ```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you tried coding this already, perhaps you can share your code to better help with the areas you're having a hard time with. Please explain what is giving you a hard time, what kinds of errors you are saying, and behaviours you expect with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can! Concatenate them together using `cats()`. This is assuming `id` is a character. If it is numeric, you need to create a new column.

```
data want;
    set have;
    id = cats(id, '_', suffix);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Stu. Is it possible then to convert the Ids from characters back to numeric?

Comment: The new ID vales contain underscores (`_`) so they are not valid numeric values. If you used a period instead of underscore then it would be possible to convert to numeric.